# How to make BLE Server Notify only when status has changed?

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-ide, esp32

I am working with ble on my esp32 using Arduino IDE and am trying to make it so when someone turns a led on, the esp32 notifies the client with either 'ON' or 'OFF'. Currently with my code the update is sent every time it loops but I only want to notify whenever the value of pin 15 changes.

I think I need to explore the same concept of someone who would want to send a serial.print whenever something changes.

Here is my relevant code.

```
if (deviceConnected) {
    if(digitalRead(15)==LOW){
      pCharacteristic->setValue("ON");

    }
    else{
      pCharacteristic->setValue("OFF");

    }
    pCharacteristic->notify();
```

I found this example bit of code but am unsure if it's helpful or how to combine it into mine

```
int old_something;

void loop ()
{
 int something = get_my_data ();
 if (something != old_something)
   Serial.print (something);  // display if it changed
 old_something = something;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Here it now works

```
//Way at the Top
boolean oldState = LOW;

//Down in Loop
 boolean newState = digitalRead(15);

  if (deviceConnected) {
    if (newState != oldState) {
      if (newState == LOW) {
        pCharacteristic->setValue("ON");

      }
      else {
        pCharacteristic->setValue("OFF");

      }
      pCharacteristic->notify();
    };

    oldState = newState;
```